# How to specify new GCC path for CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake

My OS is centos which has a default gcc in path `/usr/bin/gcc`. But it is old, I need a new version of gcc. So I install a new version in a new path `/usr/local/bin/gcc`.

But when I run `cmake`, it still uses the old version gcc path(`/usr/bin/gcc`) . How can I specify the gcc to new path(`/usr/local/bin/gcc`).

I have tried to overwrite `/usr/bin/gcc` with `/usr/local/bin/gcc`, but it not work.

Comment: I think it's a good practice to install alternate gcc version into `/opt` rather than `/usr/local`. Preferably `/opt/gcc-x.y.z`. This way, if you need an even newer version, you won't have any trouble uninstalling the previous one.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Do not overwrite `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`, but export `CC` (and `CXX`) before calling cmake:

```sh
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++
cmake /path/to/your/project
make
```

The export only needs to be done once, the first time you configure the project, then those values will be read from the CMake cache.

---

**UPDATE**: longer explanation on why not overriding `CMAKE_C(XX)_COMPILER` after Jake's comment

I recommend against overriding the `CMAKE_C(XX)_COMPILER` value for two main reasons: because it won't play well with CMake's cache and because it breaks compiler checks and tooling detection.

When using the `set` command, you have three options:

- without cache, to create a normal variable
- with cache, to create a cached variable
- force cache, to always force the cache value when configuring

Let's see what happens for the three possible calls to `set`:

**Without cache**

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++)
```

When doing this, you create a "normal" variable `CMAKE_C(XX)_COMPILER` that hides the cache variable of the same name. That means your compiler is now hard-coded in your build script and you cannot give it a custom value. This will be a problem if you have multiple build environments with different compilers. You could just update your script each time you want to use a different compiler, but that removes the value of using CMake in the first place.

Ok, then, let's update the cache...

**With cache**

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang CACHE PATH "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++ CACHE PATH "")
```

This version will just "not work". The `CMAKE_C(XX)_COMPILER` variable is already in the cache, so it won't get updated unless you force it.

Ah... let's use the force, then...

**Force cache**

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++ CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
```

This is almost the same as the "normal" variable version, the only difference is your value will be set in the cache, so users can see it. But any change will be overwritten by the `set` command.

**Breaking compiler checks and tooling**

Early in the configuration process, CMake performs checks on the compiler: Does it work? Is it able to produce executables? etc. It also uses the compiler to detect related tools, like `ar` and `ranlib`. When you override the compiler value in a script, it's "too late", all checks and detections are already done.

For instance, on my machine with gcc as default compiler, when using the `set` command to `/usr/bin/clang`, `ar` is set to `/usr/bin/gcc-ar-7`. When using an export before running CMake it is set to `/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/llvm-ar`.

Comment: Equivalent for the lazy, if the proper compilers are set in your $PATH:
 >        export CC=`which gcc`
 >        export CXX=`which g++`

Comment: Equivalent for the lazy, if the proper compilers are set in your $PATH:  
 `export CC=\`which gcc\`  
 export CXX=\`which g++\` `

Comment: If CC/CXX differ from path, I get `Incorrect 'gcc' version 'compiler.version=5.3' is not the one detected by
  CMake: 'GNU=4.8'
`

Comment: How do I do this if I'm on Windows?

Comment: @mr5 Not tested, but supposed you should be able to do `set CC=...` in a Command Prompt.

Comment: Why do you recommend against using CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER?

Comment: @Jake it would have been a bit too long to answer in a comment, so I updated my answer :)

Comment: Actually, setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` works well provided you do it using the command line: `$ cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ /path/to/source`.

Comment: This solution doesn’t always work. You need to clear the CMake cache for it to re-read the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables. It also assumes Bash or similar shell. This is an up-to-date answer without these limitations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494125/7328782

Comment: An even lazier solution if you want something correctly named that appears first in your path `export CC=gcc-11` or just `export CC=clang` works.@gerardw

Answer (score 46):

This question is quite old but still turns up on Google Search. The accepted question wasn't working for me anymore and seems to be aged. The latest information about cmake is written in the [cmake FAQ](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-different-compiler).

There are various ways to change the path of your compiler. One way would be

> Set the appropriate `CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER` variable(s) to a valid compiler
>   name or full path on the command-line using `cmake -D`. For example:
>
> ```
> cmake -G "Your Generator" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-4.2 -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.2 path/to/your/source
> ```

instead of `gcc-4.2` you can write the `path/to/your/compiler` like this

```
 cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/gcc/bin/gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/gcc/bin/g++ .
```

Comment: I was doing so while building an old project on an old compiler (GCC 5.3) while a newer compiler (GCC 7.3) was sourced in the environment. It built fine and worked on my machine, but once I moved the executable to a different machine I realized the program is linked to libstdc++.so from the sourced 7.3 instead of the requested 5.3...

Comment: This works for me while the accepted one did not.

Answer (score 8):

Set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to your new path.

See here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Answer (score 5):

## Change `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER` path without triggering a reconfigure

I wanted to compile with an alternate compiler, but also pass -D options on the command-line which would get wiped out by setting a different compiler. This happens because it triggers a re-configure. The trick is to disable the compiler detection with `NONE`, set the paths with `FORCE`, then `enable_language`.

```
project( sample_project NONE )

set( COMPILER_BIN /opt/compiler/bin )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${COMPILER_BIN}/clang CACHE PATH "clang" FORCE )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${COMPILER_BIN}/clang++ CACHE PATH "clang++" FORCE )

enable_language( C CXX )
```

## Use a Toolchain file

The more sensible choice is to create a toolchain file.

```
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin )

set( COMPILER_BIN /opt/compiler/bin )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${COMPILER_BIN}/clang CACHE PATH "clang" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${COMPILER_BIN}/clang++ CACHE PATH "clang++" )
```

Then you invoke Cmake with an additional flag

```
cmake -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/toolchain_file.cmake ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Export should be specific about which version of GCC/G++ to use, because if user had multiple compiler version, it would not compile successfully.

```
 export CC=path_of_gcc/gcc-version
 export CXX=path_of_g++/g++-version
 cmake  path_of_project_contain_CMakeList.txt
 make
```

In case project use C++11 this can be handled by using `-std=C++-11` flag in CMakeList.txt

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to configure your project through cmake-gui, starting from a clean build directory. Among the options you have available at the beginning, there's the possibility to choose the exact path to the compilers

Answer (score 2):

This not only works with `cmake`, but also with `./configure` and `make`:

```
./configure CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++
```

Which is resulting in:

```
checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
```

Answer (score 0):

RE Guillaume's answer:

Why yes, you can just swap swap `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, but you need to do that before "initializing" the project:

```
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER <path/to/c/compiler>)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER <path/to/c++/compiler>)
    project(PROJECT_NAME)
```

CMake actually performs those checks (in this case it actually doesn't since the existence of those variables indicates to it that it had already detected a working compiler, so no need to check it) when you do the project "initialization", so if you do the swapping before that, it checks your newly swapped variables.

Though, better to set `CC` and `CXX` environment variables:

```
    set(ENV{CC} <path/to/compiler>)
    set(ENV{CXX} <path/to/compiler>)
    project(PROJECT_NAME)
```

That way CMake also performs compiler checks.

Not sure this is the "correct" way to do it, but works for me ("computing" the compiler location I need when running CMake script, and swapping the default one for it).