# Compile an OpenMP program with CMake on OS X

Tags: cmake, openmp

I have a very simple openmp hello world program as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("hello, from %d.\n", id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile it in my terminal with `gcc-5 -fopenmp hello.c -o hello.o`

But I want to code in CLion, it uses CMake to organize project, when I just click the run button, I will got an error

```
fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
```

I did search in google, and add something into my CMakeLists.txt file

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(openmp)

OPTION (USE_OpenMP "Use OpenMP" ON)
IF(USE_OpenMP)
    FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP)
IF(OPENMP_FOUND)
    SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
ENDIF()
ENDIF()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")

set(SOURCE_FILES hello.c omp.c)
add_executable(openmp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is C, not C++, so instead of changing `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, change `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fopenmp")
```

And set your C compiler to gcc-5:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /your/path/to/gcc-5)
```

To know gcc-5 path, in a terminal, type `which gcc-5`

See also: [How to specify new gcc path for cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275650/1212012)

Comment: thank you for your answer! 
i have added this line to my CMakeList file, but i still got this error
 **clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'**
 i know maybe the clion use the default gcc, it needs to be gcc-5, so could you tell me how to modify to make it works, thanks again

Comment: CLion uses GCC set from CMake. So if you use CMake aligned with GCC 5, CLion will use it as well. So yes, just follow the answer above.