# Can't specify C compiler on CMake 3.7.2

Tags: c#, cmake

I'm currently working on a kinect for a school project. We want to use the skeleton tracking system, we work on W10 using c#. We tried a lot of tutorials, the last one is there : https://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started

We followed the tutorial, but we're stucked during the *Configuring with cmake-gui* part. We have to initialize CMake and to give him the compilers (C and C++), but we failed.

Error report :

> The C compiler identification is unknown The CXX compiler
>   identification is unknown CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (PROJECT): 
>   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (PROJECT):   No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
>   could be found.

In fact, it's like CMake can't find our compilers. Visual Studio 14 is installed and it can compile a "hello world", so there are some compilers for sure. So we tried to specifie those manualy, and we're lost. We googled it, without success. We tried to find the compilers (vbc.exe or cl.exe but it didn't work) then to force CMake recognize it.

Comment: Have a look at this question (probably a duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/q/17275348/2799037 pass `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=<pathToCCompiler>` and `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=<pathToCXXCompiler>`

Comment: Which [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) do you use? It is printed in cmake-gui somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. CMake uses the Windows's Registry and Environment Variables to identify your Visual Studio version and install path. So I'm wondering where your VS installation comes from and why both could not be found? Possible duplicate of [CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project): No CMAKE\_C\_COMPILER could be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys !