# Compiling an existing C++ program using Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

Edit: **not solved**, but as I moved on to [other software](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07399), I ran into other challenges.

For a research project, I downloaded a [Github project](https://github.com/OpenGP/htrack) (Tagliasacchi *et al.*, 2015) for computer vision to Linux 16.04. I have programming experience with PHP but I am new to C++. When I try to replicate the [results of the study](https://youtu.be/rm3YnClSmIQ) on my computer, I run early into a compiling error.

1. The Hello world-example of the Github project (apps » helloworld) works fine.
2. When trying to compile another application, I run into an error with the Makefile: `cmake .` works fine and some files are created. However, `make` does not work.
3. After the error, `g++ [filename].cpp -o main` obviously does not work.

How to solve this and get the dependencies right?

1. In some cases, there is a Makefile, but I run into an error:

   `[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/helloworld_atb.dir/main.cpp.o
   /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/g++-4.8: not found
   CMakeFiles/helloworld_atb.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/helloworld_atb.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloworld_atb.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 127
   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/helloworld_atb.dir/all' failed
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloworld_atb.dir/all] Error 2
   Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
   make: *** [all] Error 2`
2. In other cases (e.g. in tracker » HandFinder), I can't run either `cmake .` or `make` and compiling using `g++ HandFinder.cpp -o handfinder` does not work:

   `In file included from HandFinder.cpp:1:0:
   HandFinder.h:2:41: fatal error: tracker/ForwardDeclarations.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.`

Comment: "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/g++-4.8: not found" Try to fix that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275650/7703564) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I first execute `export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc` and `export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++` (as suggested by Jodocus), the `cmake` command seems to work. However, when I try to compile main.cpp, I get the error `helloworld_atb/main.cpp:2:18: fatal error: QDebug: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

Comment: You need to install the Qt libraries and set the paths accordingly as well.