# How to indicate gcc version for cmake?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, ubuntu-14.04

I am having multi-version of GCC in ubuntu, `gcc-4.8` and `gcc-5`. Using `gcc -v` will gives `gcc version 4.8.4`, so looks like the default is 4.8, but I need to use the `gcc-5`.

I tried [How to specify new GCC path for CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275348/how-to-specify-new-gcc-path-for-cmake):

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-5
// find the path by using 'which gcc-5'
```

and specific:

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-5 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-5
```

but gives an error:

```
ubuntu@skc:~/jumanpp-2.0.0-rc2/bld$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Jumanpp -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-5 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-5
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-5 -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc-5" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by [changing the default GCC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781972/how-can-i-update-gcc-5-3-to-6-1):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6
```

(I need higher version, so change from 4.8 to 6)